# How to convert this Javascript variable to valid JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

I am parsing out some data that's written out as a JavaScript variable currently, but I would like to convert it to valid JSON so I can parse it out that way. Here's what the variable looks like:

```
var machines = [{
    category: "Category 1",
        items: [{
            name: "Test 1",
            description: "Lorem Ipsum"
        }, {
            name: "Test 2",
            description: "Lorem Ipsum"
        }]
    }, {
    category: "Category 2",
        items: [{
            name: "Test 3",
            description: "Lorem Ipsum"
        }, {
            name: "Test 4",
            description: "Lorem Ipsum"
        }]
    }
];
```

I know I have to remove the `var machines =` part, but besides that I'm not sure how to make this valid JSON.

Comment: `JSON.stringify(machines)`

Comment: Simply `JSON.stringify(machines);`.

Comment: You say you need to remove var machines/ does that mean that the entire block of code shown is stored as a variable, as opposed to being stored as JS code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass it through `JSON.stringify()`.

```js
var machines = [{
  category: "Category 1",
  items: [{
    name: "Test 1",
    description: "Lorem Ipsum"
  }, {
    name: "Test 2",
    description: "Lorem Ipsum"
  }]
}, {
  category: "Category 2",
  items: [{
    name: "Test 3",
    description: "Lorem Ipsum"
  }, {
    name: "Test 4",
    description: "Lorem Ipsum"
  }]
}];


var json = JSON.stringify(machines);
console.log(json);
```

Comment: Thank you, that is a very handy method!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use native **[JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)** method.

Here's a working **DEMO**:

```js
var machines = [{
  category: "Category 1",
  items: [{
    name: "Test 1",
    description: "Lorem Ipsum"
  }, {
    name: "Test 2",
    description: "Lorem Ipsum"
  }]
}, {
  category: "Category 2",
  items: [{
    name: "Test 3",
    description: "Lorem Ipsum"
  }, {
    name: "Test 4",
    description: "Lorem Ipsum"
  }]
}];

var json = JSON.stringify(machines);
console.log(json);
```